# Firebase startAfter is not working for doc ref

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Docs I am following: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

I have code like below;

```
async List(query: any): Promise<Array<any>> {
    let collectionQuery = super.GetCollectionReference();
    if (query.VideoChannelId) {
      collectionQuery = collectionQuery.where(
        "VideoChannel.Id",
        "==",
        query.VideoChannelId
      );
    }
    let startAfterDoc: any = "";
    if (query.StartAfter) {
      startAfterDoc = await super.GetDocumentReference(query.StartAfter);
    }
    collectionQuery = collectionQuery
      .orderBy(query.OrderBy, "desc")
      .startAfter(startAfterDoc)
      .limit(query.Limit);
    let items = await super.List(collectionQuery);
    return items;
  }
```

And utility methods:

```
 GetDocumentReference(id: string): any {
    return this.GetCollectionReference().doc(id);
  }
  async GetDocumentSnapshot(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return await this.GetDocumentReference(id).get();
  }
  GetCollectionReference(): any {
    return this.db.collection(this.CollectionName);
  }
```

Regardless what ever value I pass for query.StartAfter it always returns top document in the collection.
 I am pretty sure document exists with id query.StartAfter.

If I use `GetDocumentSnapshot` instead of `GetCollectionReference`, then I am getting `parse error at firebase API`.

Indexes has been added for `query.OrderBy` (CreateDate) and Id fields.

What possibly I would be missing here?